# How many abelian groups of order $p^{5}$ are there?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I want to find how many abelian groups of order $p^{5}$ there are, up to isomorphism, where $p$ is a prime number.  Are there any theorems that can help with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit: Adding my answer of your question in comments:**

To use the theorem you must factor suppose $\vert G \vert=n$ and factor $n$ into prime factors. Then you must get divisors $d_1,d_2,\dots,d_m$ such that $d_i\mid d_{i+1}$, and $d_1\cdot\dots\cdot d_{m}=n$, and your group can be

$$G\cong \mathbb{Z}_{d_1}\oplus \mathbb{Z}_{d_2}\oplus \dots \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{d_m} $$

**Original answer**

Yes, the theorem that you're looking for is the [fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely_generated_abelian_group). From this you have that $p^5$ can factor into

$$p^5=p^5$$ 
$$p^5=p\cdot p^4$$ 
$$p^5=p^2\cdot p^3$$ 
$$p^5=p\cdot p\cdot p^3$$ 
$$p^5=p\cdot p^2\cdot p^2$$ 
$$p^5=p\cdot p\cdot p\cdot p^2$$ 
$$p^5=p\cdot p\cdot p\cdot p\cdot p$$

So you have all the direct sums of that groups.

$$G\cong\mathbb{Z}_{p^5}$$ 
$$G\cong\mathbb{Z}_{p}\oplus \mathbb{Z}_{p^4}$$ 
$$G\cong\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}\oplus \mathbb{Z}_{p^3}$$ 
$$G\cong\mathbb{Z}_{p}\oplus \mathbb{Z}_{p}\oplus \mathbb{Z}_{p^3}$$ 
$$G\cong\mathbb{Z}_{p}\oplus \mathbb{Z}_{p^2}\oplus \mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$$ 
$$G\cong\mathbb{Z}_{p}\oplus \mathbb{Z}_p\oplus \mathbb{Z}_{p}\oplus \mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$$ 
$$G\cong\mathbb{Z}_{p}\oplus \mathbb{Z}_p\oplus \mathbb{Z}_p\oplus \mathbb{Z}_{p}\oplus \mathbb{Z}_{p}$$

Comment: In order to use this theorem does $p$ have to be prime?

Comment: @MomoTheSir I added the answer of your question to my original question.

Comment: What do you mean when you say $d_i\mid d_{i+1}$?  For example say $|G| = 20 = 2^{2} \cdot 5$, are you saying that I cannot apply the theorem here since 2 does not divide 5?

Comment: Yes, you can apply the theorem, for example $d_1=2$ and $d_2=10$ so $G\cong \mathbb{Z}_2\oplus \mathbb{Z}_{10}$.

Comment: Oh I see.  So you broke $2^2 \cdot 5$ into $2 \cdot 10$?

Comment: Yes, the idea is to have all the prime factors, because all the elements must divide the next, so you must know that if $p$ divides $d_1$, then $p$ must divide all the next $d_i$'s, so you must know the number of $p$ factors have $n$ to know if you're doing correctly.