# How to find all abelian groups of order 180?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

How would I find, up to isomorphism, a list of all abelian groups of order 180?  Would I simply use the fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups by breaking 180 into prime factors, $180 = 2^2 3^2 5$?

Also, how would I find a group in the list that had an element of order $18$?  I was thinking of using a theorem that states that if $G$ is abelian and $|G| = pk$, where $p$ is a prime, then $G$ has an element of order $p$.  However, $18$ is not a prime.

Edit: I now know that I can use the fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups to the first part of my question, but the second part to my question still holds.

Comment: You asked a question equal to this one, but using $p^5$ instead of $180$. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2022131/how-many-abelian-groups-of-order-p5-are-there/2022137#2022137

Comment: I asked this question before I realized the theorem also applies to a product of prime factors.  Let me fix this question.

Answer (score 1):

There is a theorem that is seldomly mentionned in notebooks but is sometimes quite useful:*Every finite Abelian group can uniquely be written as $\Bbb Z_{n_1} \oplus \ldots \oplus \Bbb Z_{n_k}$ where $n_1|\ldots|n_{k}$*.
 In our case this gives us:

1. $\Bbb Z_{180}$
2. $\Bbb Z_2 \times \Bbb Z_{90}$
3. $\Bbb Z_3 \times \Bbb Z_{60}$
4. $\Bbb Z_6 \times \Bbb Z_{30}$

Answer (score 0):

Since you know how to apply the the fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups for the first part, I will only answer the second part.

For the second part of your question you need that one of the $\mathbb{Z}_{d_i}$ factors to be divisible by $9$. If you only have only one $d_i$ (in this case $d_1$), the only case you can have is $\mathbb{Z}_{180}$, so this case lets you a generated group of order 180, and you can consider the element $10$, that is of order $18$.

If you have $d_1$ and $d_2$, (that are the same that I told in the answer of [your question before,](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2022131/how-many-abelian-groups-of-order-p5-are-there/2022137#2022137)) it must happen that $d_1=2$ and $d_2=2\cdot 9\cdot 5$ (because $d_1$ must divide $d_2$, and this is the only group of order $180$ that can have an element of order $18$.

The fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups states that your group will descompose into $\mathbb{Z}_{d_1}\oplus\dots \mathbb{Z}_{d_m}$, where $d_i\mid d_{i+1}$ and 
$$d_1\cdot \dots d_m=\vert G \vert$$

So if you have that $5$ divides $d_1$, then divides $d_2$ too, so you must have that $25\mid 180$, but that's not true.

If you have that $3\mid d_1$, then $d_1=3$ or $2\cdot3$, so $d_2=5\cdot 4\cdot 3$ or $3\cdot 5$, but this implies that your group has structure

$$\mathbb{Z}_{3}\oplus \mathbb{Z}_{60} \text{ or } \mathbb{Z}_{6}\oplus \mathbb{Z}_{15}$$

But is clear that any of them has an element of order $18$ since any of them has an element of order $9$ because of their structure.

Comment: Do you mean that the order of $\mathbb{Z}_{d_i}$ be divisible by 9?  Also, why must it be divisible by 9 to have an element of order 18?

Comment: Because the elements of the group are determined by the structure of the group. If you only have a sum of subgroups of order not divisible by $9$, then it can't happen to you to have an element of order $9$. I tried to explain in the answer again.

Comment: @MonsieurGalois, how about the group $Z_4\oplus Z_{45} = Z_4 \oplus Z_9 \oplus Z_5$ and the element $(2, 1, 0)$? :)

Comment: @SashaMayer I forgot that case, but, that's the case when $d_1=180$

Comment: @MonsieurGalois, remaining group with such element is $V_4\oplus Z_{45} $, btw

Comment: @SashaMayer That last case is with $d_1=2$ and $d_2=90$, that is the one that I put.

Comment: @SashaMayer $V_4\oplus Z_{45}$ is exactly the same as $Z_2\oplus Z_2\oplus Z_9 \oplus Z_5\cong Z_2\oplus Z_{90}$

Comment: @MonsieurGalois, i think, that the easiest way to find the element is to notice that the order of product of to elements is least common multiple of orders. From this it immediately follows that the group must contain $Z_9$ in it's decomposition. And as for abelian with 4 elements, both cases ($V_4$ and $Z_4$) are possible.

Comment: Well, if he wants the element, yes, you can see the group as the direct sum, then you identify the element, but he wanted the groups which contain elements of order 18.

Comment: @MonsieurGalois, and also $V_4\oplus Z_{45} \simeq Z_{10} \oplus Z_{18}$, there are still many alternatives:)

Comment: The idea of clarifying it as the direct sum of Z2 and Z90 was to relate the answer to the concepts used in the fundamental theorem for finitely generated abelian groups, which he didn't know two hours ago. That's the why of my specification.