# Different Definition of Fundamental Theorem of Finitely Generated Abelian Groups

Tags: group-theory, definition, abelian-groups, finitely-generated

I was reading about abelian groups but confused in Fundamental Theorem of Finitely Generated Abelian Groups, so I searched
some sources and become even more confused due to the different types of definition found.

1)
(from Abstract algebra Dummit and Foote)

**Theorem.** (*Fundamental Theorem of Finitely Generated Abelian Groups*) Let $G$ be a finitely generated abelian group. Then

**(1)** $G \cong \mathbb{Z}^r \times Z_{n_1} \times Z_{n_2} \times ... \times Z_{n_s}$, for some integers $r$, $n_1$, $n_2$, ... , $n_s$ satisfying the following conditions: **(a)** $r \ge 0$ and $n_j \ge 2$ for all $j$, and **(b)** $n_{i+1} \mid n_i$ for $1 \le i \le s-1$

**(2)** the expression in (1) is unique: if $G\cong \mathbb{Z}^t \times Z_{m_1} \times Z_{m_2} \times ... \times Z_{m_u}$, where $t$ and $m_1$, $m_2$, ... , $m_u$ satisfy (a) and (b) (i.e., $t \ge 0$, $m_j \ge 2$ for all $j$ and $m_{i+1} \mid m_i$ for $1 \le i \le u-1$), then $t = r$, $u = s$ and $m_i = n_i$ for all $i$.

[$\:\:\:2.$](https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/notes/group/fgabelian.html)

(I can see that second definition is not for isomorphism but still,)
$$A = \mathbb{Z}^n \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{h_1} \oplus ... \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{h_n}$$
$$where \::h_i | h_{i+1}$$

[$\: \; \:3.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2022131/how-many-abelian-groups-of-order-p5-are-there)

To use the theorem you must factor suppose $\vert G \vert=n$ and factor $n$ into prime factors. Then you must get divisors $d_1,d_2,\dots,d_m$ such that $d_i\mid d_{i+1}$, and $d_1\cdot\dots\cdot d_{m}=n$, and your group can be

$$G\cong \mathbb{Z}_{d_1}\oplus \mathbb{Z}_{d_2}\oplus \dots \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{d_m} $$

I looked in Wikipedia but they only say about uniqueness but don't have these definitions with divisibility.

Can someone please explain why there is difference in the divisibility conditions in these definition and what each means.

I am new to these so please forgive my negligence.

Comment: Well, 2) and 3) are writing the factors so that the "subscripts" are in increasing order, while, 1) has them in decreasing order. I'm not sure what your other questions/issues are.

Comment: Is your concern about the order of the invariant factors? There's a natural isomorphism permuting summands: $\mathbb{Z}_a \oplus \mathbb{Z}_b \cong \mathbb{Z}_b \oplus \mathbb{Z}_a$ that allows you to go between the two conventions.

Comment: @SammyBlack Thanks, can I also permute in my second definition ?

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC sorry for not being clear, but my concern was about order of the invariant factor in different definitions

Comment: Ah, I guess Sammy Black pinpointed your issue.